# How do I draw lines perpendicular to contour lines on ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting the voltage in a pool of water with two electrodes.

I have contour lines on my graph at every volt, but I would like to show the electric field lines which are going to be perpendicular to the contour lines.  How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17318/245). It's 2D, so not a duplicate, but related.

Answer (score 13):

What you're asking for could be done, but perpendicular contour lines are *not a good way* to represent the electric field in a **3D** plot of a **2D** potential. The electric field (or negative gradient) will be a vector field in the plane, and its field lines will be planar too. The third dimension in your **3d** plot is geometrically meaningless because it doesn't have dimension *length*.

So instead what I'd strongly suggest is to either plot your potential *and* field in 2D, or plot the electric field as **planar vectors** attached to the 3D plot of the potential. The latter is what I'm illustrating below, because it's most closely matched to your starting point:

```
fieldArrow[pos_, field_, scale_] := {Hue[Norm[field]], 
   Arrowheads[.02], Arrow[Tube[{{pos, pos + scale field}}]]};

grid = Table[{x, y}, {y, 0, 10, .5}, {x, 0, 10, .5}];

gridData = 
  Table[Sin[y/10] ArcTan[x - 5], {y, 0, 10, .5}, {x, 0, 10, .5}];

fieldX = -DerivativeFilter[gridData, {0, 1}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3];
fieldY = -DerivativeFilter[gridData, {1, 0}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3];
data3D = MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {grid, gridData}, 2];

vectorField = 
  MapThread[
   fieldArrow[Append[#1, #2], {#3, #4, 0}, 3] &, {grid, gridData, 
    fieldX, fieldY}, 2];

arrows = Graphics3D[vectorField];

Show[ListPlot3D[Flatten[data3D, 1], MeshFunctions -> (#3 &)], arrows]
```

[image: field and potential]

Here, I take the gradient of a made-up potential given as data, by using `GradientFilter`. Then I make arrows out of the field vectors and superimpose them on your original plot with `Show`.

It's up to you to style the arrows differently - I colored them by the field strength
and scaled them by a parameter `scale` in the function `fieldArrow`. You may also want to shrink the arrowheads proportionally to the arrow length. But I left that out so you can see the smaller arrows better.

Answer (score 12):

One can do what you ask, but you might prefer to follow the advice of @Jens.  Here's how, anyway.  First, I made up some data for a similar potential function.

```
data = Table[10 + (3 ((20 - j)^2 - (j + 5)^2))/(75 + (i - 10)^2 + 2 (j - 10)^2),
     {j, 0, 20}, {i, 0, 20}];
f = ListInterpolation[data, {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}];
```

Then we combine a plot of the potential and a stream plot of the negative gradient field, mapping the streamlines onto the graph of the potential (*edited*).

```
pot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
   Mesh -> 14, FaceGrids -> All];
vf = StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  StreamStyle -> "Line"];
Show[pot,
 Graphics3D[vf[[1]] /. {{x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, f[x, y]}}]
 ]
```

[image: Potential with contours and gradient lines]

An alternative presentation might be the graph of the potential alongside a combined plot of the contours/gradient paths.

```
vf = StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  StreamStyle -> ColorData[1][3]];
cp = Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, Contours -> 14], vf];
Row[{Show[pot, ImageSize -> 300], Show[cp, ImageSize -> 250]}]
```

[image: Potential and contour plots]

Comment: It does *look* nice, though (+1).

Comment: +1 btw maybe an option of `StreamStyle -> "Line"` would make it more accordant with what OP asked for *lines*.

Comment: @Silvia  Thanks.  I'd forgotten about such options and had to replace `Arrow` by `Line`.  It's simpler now (in the edit), although I kept the arrows for the plane contour plot.  Maybe someday *Mathematica* will have an option `Mesh -> "Gradient"` :)