# Plot 2D Vector function in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

I want to plot a 2D vector function such as $F(x,y) = (a(x,y),\,b(x,y))$ in a 3D graph so that the vectors are embedded in the xy plane. I tried to do the following:

First I defined a piecewise function like this

```
g[z_] := Piecewise[{{1, z == 0}}, 0]
```

Then I converted the 2D vector function to a 3D one by setting the 3rd component to zero and multiplying 1st and 2nd components by `g[z]` so that the x and y components are null when `z != 0`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := {x g[z], y g[z], 0};
```

Plot the function:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x g[z], y g[z],0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

The issue with this solution is that `VectorPlot3D` won't evaluate the function in the relevant points, The above example shows an empty graph, because *Mathematica* jumps from `z = -1` to `z = 1` without evaluating `z = 0`.

I tried with `RegionFunction` (which would've rendered the definition of the above-mentioned piecewise function useless), but that only accepts inequalities, and I want to evaluate the function at any coordinate `{x ,y, 0}`.

I could feed it a list of vectors via `VectorPoints -> { {a, b, 0}, {c, d, 0}, ...}`, but that's not an elegant solution at all. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Not a duplicate but an answer related to a comment below by @DvD: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/how-do-i-draw-lines-perpendicular-to-contour-lines-on-listplot3d/18771#18771

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 RegionFunction -> ((-.1 < #3 < .1) &),
 VectorPoints -> {8, 8, 3},
 VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D",
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 VectorScale -> Scaled[0.15]]
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine, although I don't fully understand the syntax. What does #3 mean? Does it represent the third argument of the function? And what does the & operator do?

Comment: @DvD #3 represents vertical coordinate z. If I wouldn't put limitation with `RegionFunction`, you would see many parallel identical planes. I limited plotting to a narrow region around a single plane with a constraint in z-coordinate `(-.1 < #3 < .1) &`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Graphics3D[
  VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}][[1, 2]] /. 
    Arrow[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] :> Arrow[{{x1, y1, 0}, {x2, y2, 0}}
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Combining this result with some other graphs (such as a scalar function) is a bit troubling, but it's helpful to know nevertheless!

Comment: @DvD This figure should combine with other graphics just fine. Have you tried `Show`?

Comment: Um, back when I formulated my comment, it just showed some huge arrows for some reason. I tried it again and it works now. I can't tell what I did differently this time.