# Plotting separatrices for nonlinear system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

Consider the system:

\begin{align*}
x'&=(1-x-y)x\\
y'&=(4-7x-3y)y
\end{align*}

The system has a saddle point at (1/4,3/4). How can I plot the separatrices on the phase portrait having domain $\{(x,y):\ 0\le x\le 1,\ 0\le y\le 2\}$?

Here is my attempt. Start with a vector plot.

```
Clear[x, y];
Clear[Derivative];
f[x_, y_] = (1 - x - y) x;
g[x_, y_] = (4 - 7 x - 3 y) y;
vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2},
   VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.5, None},
   VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]},
   VectorPoints -> 16,
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
```

Get the equilibrium points.

```
eqpts = Solve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

There is a saddle point at (1/4,3/4). Set an eps value.

```
eps=1/10000;
```

Define a function.

```
sol[{x0_, y0_, tmin_, tmax_}] := 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
   x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

Spend time (brute force) adjusting arguments to sol function to plot the separatrices.

```
sep1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 + eps, 3/4, 0, 40}], {t, 0, 40},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 - eps, 3/4, 0, 40}], {t, 0, 40},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep3 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 + eps, 3/4 + eps, -2.8, 0}], {t, -2.8, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep4 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 - eps, 3/4 - eps, -40, 0}], {t, -40, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
```

Show everything together.

```
Show[vp, Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{x, y}] /. eqpts}], sep1, sep2, sep3, sep4]
```

Result:

[image]

Which worked. Just wondering if there would be a simpler approach, one that beginning students can easily understand.

P.S. All code pasted below for an easy copy and paste.

```
Clear[x, y];
Clear[Derivative];
f[x_, y_] = (1 - x - y) x;
g[x_, y_] = (4 - 7 x - 3 y) y;
vp = VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2},
   VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.5, None},
   VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]},
   VectorPoints -> 16,
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
eqpts = Solve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
eps = 1/10000;
sol[{x0_, y0_, tmin_, tmax_}] := 
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}];
sep1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 + eps, 3/4, 0, 40}], {t, 0, 40},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 - eps, 3/4, 0, 40}], {t, 0, 40},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep3 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 + eps, 3/4 + eps, -2.8, 0}], {t, -2.8, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
sep4 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@sol[{1/4 - eps, 3/4 - eps, -40, 0}], {t, -40, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
Show[vp, Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{x, y}] /. eqpts}], sep1, sep2, sep3, sep4]
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/basins-of-attraction), might get you started.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can solve (approximately) for the initial conditions of solutions that approach an equilbrium by comparing the displacement vector from the equilibrium with the vector field of the ODE.  Such trajectory is characterized by the condition that these two vectors become parallel as the solution nears the equilibrium.  I used a similar idea before, which is buried in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38613/how-to-solve-a-stiff-nonlinear-second-order-ode/38671#38671).

```
sys = {(1 - x - y) x, (4 - 7 x - 3 y) y};
vars = {x, y};
equilibria = Solve[sys == {0, 0}, vars, Reals]
(*  {{x -> 0, y -> 4/3}, {x -> 1/4, y -> 3/4}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}  *)

saddles = Pick[equilibria, Sign@Det@D[sys, {vars}] /. equilibria, -1]
(*  {{x -> 1/4, y -> 3/4}}  *)
```

Here is a function to get initial conditions for the separatrices.

```
sepICS[p0_, eps_] := With[{p1 = p0 + eps * Norm[p0] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}},
   p1 /. NSolve[Det[{p1 - p0, sys /. Thread[vars -> p1]}] == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi]
   ];
```

We get parametrizations for the separatrices, stopping the integration when the solution gets close to the saddle and when it leaves the plot domain.  One problem with approaching a saddle point is that the initial condition, as well as the subsequent integration, is approximate.  If the solution is pushed too far, it will ricochet off along another separatrix (approximately).

```
separatrices = Flatten[
   Module[{eps = 10^-7,         (* tunable distance from equilibrium *)
     X0, dX},
    With[{Xa = 0, Xb = 1, Yc = 0, Yd = 2,  (* plot domain boundaries *)
        p0 = vars /. #,         (* equilibrium *)
        X = Through[vars[t]]},  (* variables at t *)
       X0 = X /. t -> 0;        (* initial values *)
       dX = D[X, t];            (* derivatives *)
       With[{X1 = X[[1]], X2 = X[[2]]},
        First@NDSolve[{
             dX == (sys /. v : Alternatives @@ vars :> v[t]), 
             X0 == #,
             (*stop when close to saddle*)
             WhenEvent[Norm[X - p0] < 0.5 eps * Norm[p0], "StopIntegration"],
             (*stop when solution leaves plot domain*)
             WhenEvent[Abs[X1 - (Xa + Xb)/2] > (Xb - Xa)/2, "StopIntegration"], 
             WhenEvent[Abs[X2 - (Yc + Yd)/2] > (Yd - Yc)/2, "StopIntegration"]},
            vars, {t, -100, 100}] & /@ sepICS[p0, eps]
        ]] & /@ saddles
    ],
 1];


sepPlots = ParametricPlot @@@ ({{x[t], y[t]}, 
       Hold[Flatten][{t, x["Domain"]}]} /. separatrices // ReleaseHold);

Show[
 background,
 vp,
 sepPlots,
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The background is some attempt at mimicking [ubpqdn's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1997/ubpdqn).  One can use the lines from the plots of the separatrices to construct poiygon's to illustrate the regions created by them.  It is a bit awkward to add the corner points.

```
sepLines = First@Cases[#, _Line, Infinity] & /@ sepPlots;
background = Graphics[
  Riffle[
   Lighter[#, 0.6] & /@ {Red, Purple, Yellow, Green},
   MapAt[Reverse, 
     Partition[sepLines, 2, 1, 1], {{2}, {4}}] /. {Line[p1_], 
      Line[p2_]} :> Polygon[
      Join[p1, p2,
       Nearest[Tuples[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}}], {p2[[-1, 1]], p1[[1, 2]]}, {1, 0.01}],
       Nearest[Tuples[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}}], {p1[[1, 1]], p2[[-1, 2]]}, {1, 0.01}]]]
   ],
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1
  ]
```

---

*Addendum: Notes on the code.*

*1.* `v : x | y :> v[t]`: The `:` is short for [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html); `|` is short for [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html). So `v : x | y` defines the pattern symbol `v` to represent `x` or `y`. The whole `v : x | y :> v[t]`, means replace `x` or `y` by `x[t]` or `y[t]` respectively. The rules `{x -> x[t], y -> y[t]}` are equivalent.

*2.* `ParametricPlot @@@ ...`:
The main problem here are the domains of the solutions. The variable `separatrices` contains a list of solutions of the form

```
{{x -> x1ifn, y -> y1ifn}, {x -> x2ifn, y -> y2ifn},...}
```

where `x1ifn`, `y1ifn` etc. are interpolating functions.  Each pair `x1ifn`, `y1ifn` has the same domain, but another pair `x2ifn`, `y2ifn` will have a different domain.  So what is an easy way to plot all of the solutions?  If `ifn` is an `InterpolatingFunction`, then `ifn["Domain"]` returns a list of domains for each input; in this case, it will have the form `{{tmin, tmax}}`.  `Flatten[{t, x["Domain"]}]` will have the form `{t, tmin, tmax}` as needed for `ParametricPlot`.  The problem is that the `x` in `x["Domain"]` has to be replaced by an `InterpolatingFunction` and evaluated before `Flatten` is evaluated.  Hence the `Hold[Flatten]`, to prevent flattening until **after** the `/. separatrices` has been executed; the `ReleaseHold` then lets the domains be evaluated and flattened. Since `separatrices` is a list of solutions (each of which is a list of `Rules`), the replacement yields a list of the form:

```
{{{x1ifn[t], y1ifn[t]}, Hold[Flatten][{t, {{tmin1, tmax1}}}]},
 {{x2ifn[t], y2ifn[t]}, Hold[Flatten][{t, {{tmin2, tmax2}}}]},
 ...}
```

After `ReleaseHold`, these elements will be ready to have `ParametricPlot` applied to them with [`@@@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).  This replaces the `{}` around each element with `ParametricPlot[]`:

```
{ParametricPlot[{x1ifn[t], y1ifn[t]}, {t, tmin1, tmax1}],
 ParametricPlot[{x2ifn[t], y2ifn[t]}, {t, tmin2, tmax2}],
 ...}
```

These automatically evaluate to the plots of each separatrix.

Comment: this is beatiful and correct answer...I will direc OP towards your answer...I was merely trying to point but am glad have learned a lot from your answer in process

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks!  I also realized I forgot to say how the displacement and the vector field are to be compared.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Absolutely wonderful answer. But I am having difficulty figuring it out. My best first question is what does (sys /. v : x | y :> v[t]) mean? I know that sys is {x (1 - x - y), (4 - 7 x - 3 y) y}. Then (sys /. v : x | y :> v[t]) returns {x[t] (1 - x[t] - y[t]), (4 - 7 x[t] - 3 y[t]) y[t]}. So it seems to replace x with x[t] and y with y[t], but why?  What does v:x | y:>v[t] mean?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Excellent answer, easily understood by me. May I now ask my next question? This command is puzzling:  sepPlots = ParametricPlot @@@ ({{x[t], y[t]}, 
       Hold[Flatten][{t, x["Domain"]}]} /. separatrices // ReleaseHold); Could you add a nice explanation of this above?

Comment: @MichaelE2 See what I just did on the following [page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80559/creating-a-nonlinear-phase-portrait)

Comment: I just found this question and as the others, I think the answer by MichaelE2 is very neat. But when I try to apply it to my system it doesn't work, since sepICS[] returns only three starting points instead of four. Unfortunately I don't really understand what's going on in sepICS[] and thus I can't fix it. <p>
Also unfortunately I can't add a comment to MichaelE2's answer since I don't have enough reputation points :-( <p>
But maybe somebody else knows a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Axel You could ask your question as a question. Refer to this Q&A and include the code for your system.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this would be helpful:

```
e1 = (1 - x - y) x;
e2 = (4 - 7 x - 3 y) y;
sp = StreamPlot[{e1, e2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}}]}];
{a, b, c, d} = 
  ImplicitRegion[#, {x, 
      y}] & /@ ({#1[e1, 0] && #2[e2, 0] && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 2} & @@@
      Tuples[{Less, Greater}, 2]);
lab = "x'(t)" <> #1 <> ", " <> "y'(t)" <> #2 & @@@ 
   Tuples[{"<0", ">0"}, 2];
With[{col = {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}}, 
 Legended[Show[sp, 
   Sequence @@ 
    MapThread[
     RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[#, PrecisionGoal -> 10], 
       PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], #2}] &, {{a, b, c, d}, col}]], 
  SwatchLegend[Lighter[#, 0.7] & /@ col, lab, 
   LegendFunction -> "Panel"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I definitely can use this in class. However, what I need is the same image, but with the separatrices, the solutions moving toward and away from the equilibrium point.

Comment: @David I would look at MichaelE2 answer and accept it as my answer merely partitions region of interest and not what you want and there  is a lot of instructive code :)

Comment: You were both equally helpful. I really appreciate your answers. I'm going to have to give a little effort to understand the coding.

Comment: @David MichaelE2's answer is beautiful, instructive and correct...mine was half-baked (if well intentioned)...done without deep thought but aimed to motivate diving in...glad the MichaelE2's answer emerged and I have also learned a lot...this is joy of this site...