# NDSolve gives only part of the path

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having a problem numerical calculating some separatrices to a dynamic model of housing price and supply.  The interpolating function fails to be solved over enough values, resulting in truncated paths.  I want paths over a wider range.

The differential equations are

```
sdot=((3.33502*10^-7)*p[t]^1.8-.036*s[t]);
pdot=(.059*p[t]-(4.2361*10^7)/s[t]);
```

The equilibrium point is

```
peq = 91300;
seq = 7864;
```

I find the separatrices by selecting points close to the equilibrium point.  For example, the separatrix to the south east is found by solving for the path that goes through (seq+1, peq-1).

```
sepse=NDSolve[{s'[t]==sdot,p'[t]==pdot,s[0]==seq+1,p[0]==peq-1},{s,p},{t,-110,0}];
```

I use NDSolve starting at t = -110 because that path goes *into* the equilibrium point at t = 0.

I plot this with arrows using

```
ParametricPlot[{s[t], p[t]} /. sepse, {t, -110, 0}, 
PlotRange -> {{5000, 10000}, {50000, 120000}}, AspectRatio -> 1] 
/.Line[s_] :> {Arrowheads[{0., .05, .05, .05, 0.}], Arrow[s]}
```

See below for the result plotted out (along with the other 3 separatrices), first by themselves, then, in a full phase diagram using StreamPlot.

**To sum up, I don't understand why the intepolating function isn't over a wider range.  Making the range of NDSolve bigger doesn't seem to help. Are the big and small numbers in sdot and pdot making this problem ill-conditioned?  Something else?  I want a solution to the path that goes at least to edge of the phase graphs below.**

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80331/4999

Comment: The interval for `t` in the linked answer would have to be enlarged a bit to get a long enough curve; `WhenEvent` stops the solution at the plot boundary.  Unless there is some objection, I will mark this as a duplicate of the other.