# Display 3D function and its gradient in same graphic

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Is it possible to display e.g., $z=x^2+y^2$ with Plot3D and in the same box, in the $z=0$ plane, plot its gradient?

Comment: Check out http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18758

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p = Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
pv = VectorPlot3D[{{2 x, 2 y, 0}, {-2 y, 2 x, 0}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
     1}, {z, -0.01, 0.01}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 1}}];
Show[pv, p]
```

[image]