# Options of ContourPlot — poor results when applied to a rapidly varying function

Tags: plotting

I am struggling to produce a proper vector plot for a certain vector field.
In detail, my vector plot is given by the partial derivatives of the function

```
F[x_, y_] := -(1/x)*(Log[x - y] + 1) + (1/x)*((-y^3/3) + 2)
```

I add a plot for the reader's convenience

```
Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, 0.5, 10}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x > y], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#3] &), 
  PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

When I try to use `StreamPlot`

```
StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 0.5, 30}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  StreamStyle -> "Line"];
```

I get very poor results. I tried with `StreamPoints -> Fine`,

```
    StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 0.5, 30}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

but it didn't help
[image]

which is clearly a poor representation, e.g. the saddle in the contour plot is not visible at all!

```
      ContourPlot[F[x, y] , {x, 0.5, 30}, {y, 0, 3}, 
      RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x > y], PlotRange -> Automatic, 
      Contours -> 45, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 30, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
      ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

I would like to have many more streamlines, allowing fine details of the surface to be represented.

I wonder if it has something to do with the function having rapidly changing gradients. When I apply the same method to a better behaved function, I get reasonable results.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I did try that, but to no avail.

Comment: I can not determine from your question how you want the plot to look. Can you elaborate on what you are aiming for.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I have added some detail, as well as the current status of the plot, which will hopefully make it clear why I am not happy with it.

Comment: When I evaluate your posted code, I don't get results that look your plots. Please check the posted code against your notebook code. If there are errors in the post, please correct them.

Comment: @m_goldberg, you are of course right, I edited accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has a singular point and a logarithmic singularity, so the vector field will be better reproduced in parts, for example

```
F[x_, y_] := -(1/x)*(Log[x - y] + 1) + (1/x)*((-y^3/3) + 2)



{p1, p2, p3, 
   p4} = {StreamPlot[
    Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 0.5, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> 20, StreamStyle -> LightYellow], 
   StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 3, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> 20, StreamStyle -> LightYellow], 
   StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 6, 9}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> 20, StreamStyle -> LightYellow], 
   StreamPlot[Evaluate[-D[F[x, y], {{x, y}}]], {x, 9, 12}, {y, 0, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> 20, StreamStyle -> LightYellow]};
f = ContourPlot[F[x, y], {x, .5, 12}, {y, 0, 3}, Contours -> 50, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False];
Show[f, p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image: fig1]

Split the whole picture into separate fragments

```
{g1, g2, g3, 
  g4} = {ContourPlot[F[x, y], {x, 0.5, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Contours -> 20, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False], 
  ContourPlot[F[x, y], {x, 3, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, Contours -> 20, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False], 
  ContourPlot[F[x, y], {x, 6, 9}, {y, 0, 3}, Contours -> 20, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False], 
  ContourPlot[F[x, y], {x, 9, 12}, {y, 0, 3}, Contours -> 20, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False]}
 {Show[g1, p1], Show[g2, p2], Show[g3, p3], Show[g4, p4]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I am not so sure though why it would be impractical to plot the vector plot over the entire region used for the contour plot in my question, Ultimately I would like to superimpose the vector plot to the countour plot, as done for example in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/how-do-i-draw-lines-perpendicular-to-contour-lines-on-listplot3d

Comment: ContourPlot also needs to be reproduced in parts. In full scale, it looks awful.

Comment: I see your point, but yet, that might be a little bit subjective. I do not find the Countour Plot that ugly.....and still it should be easy to have nice streamlines flowing perpendicular to the cointour lines...why is it not possible to make the vector plot on the whole region look better? thanks a lot

Comment: I cited a possible model. You can improve it.

Comment: many thanks indeed, very helpful...but now I am left completely puzzled, why are not the sreamlines locally perpendicular to the contour lines?? Thanks again

Comment: This is due to the change in scale in height and width. If we divide the figure into separate fragments of equal width and length, then the perpendicularity of the lines will be restored. I added a picture for illustration.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yet I cannot understand, what change in scale in height and width?? Cannot the same scale be used (is it not used already?) this aspect is really what made me think my plots were incorrect..thanks for the patience