# Plotting: Is anyone familiar with gradientfieldplot command?

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to plot this graph showing the electric field lines and lines of equipotential based off the electrode configuration(in black) of two parallel lines. This is what I've been using for other electrode configurations:

```
 gradientFieldPlot[(y^2 + (x - 7/2)^2)^(-1/2) - (y^2 + (x + 7/2)^2)^(-1/2), {x, -7, 7},  
                   {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",  
                   Contours -> 15,ContourStyle -> White, Frame -> True,
                   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, Axes -> True,
                   StreamStyle -> Orange]
```

and am trying to do it in a similar manner, but I do not know how to express the equations for these two finite parallel lines in the `[ ]`.
Can any one help? Thanks sooo much!!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `ElectroStaticPotential` example in the `ContourPlot[]` help

Comment: I've been trying everything, no luck :(

Comment: Direct link to the `ElectroStaticPotential` example in the Documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html#14946033

Comment: @Logan, When editing a question, it is best to not change the question entirely as it leaves answers hanging (why am I plotting a point charge instead of line charges?). Instead, you should **add** clarifying information. As for the line segments, experiment with  `f[x,y]=h[x-x0,y-y0,L]-h[x-x1,y-y1,L]` in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for your help Timothy!!

Comment: Logan, you should read the comments to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/plot-electric-potential-and-field?rq=1) question. I think you are probably referring to a custom plot command made by @Jens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to assume that "everything" includes some simple `ContourPlot` and `StreamPlot` attempts, but that you are getting mired in the style details of your plots (missing streamlines, streamlines not where you want them, colors, etc.)

To draw the charge distributions, we can use `Graphics`.

```
gP1 = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{14, 10}]}];
gP2 = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{7, 10}], Point[{21, 10}]}];
gP3 = Graphics[{Thickness[Large], Line[{{8, 7}, {20, 7}}], Line[{{8, 13}, {20, 13}}]}];
```

For the plots, we first need to look up the expressions for the potentials of a point charge and a charged line segment.

```
h[x_, y_] = 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
h[x_, y_, L_] = Log[(Sqrt[(x - L/2)^2 + y^2] - (x - L/2))/
                    (Sqrt[(x + L/2)^2 + y^2] - (x + L/2))];
```

Then we need to move these expressions around to represent our charge distributions.

```
f1[x_, y_] = h[x - 14, y - 10];
```

We can use `ContourPlot` on the `f` functions to get the equipotential lines. Note that `ContourPlot` uses `ContourStyle` instead of `PlotStyle` to change the color of the lines.

```
cP = ContourPlot[f1[x, y], {x, 0, 28}, {y, 0, 20},
       Contours -> 4, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Blue, 
       FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 28, 2], Range[0, 20, 2]}];
```

The field lines are perpendicular to the equipotential lines, so they are related to the gradient of the potential functions.

```
g1[x_, y_] = D[f1[x, y], {{x, y}}];
```

We can plot the field lines using `StreamPlot`. Here is where getting to know the options pays off. First, we don't want arrowheads on our lines, so we put `StreamStyle->"Line"`. In your picture, you only have 8 streamlines, so we try `StreamPoints->8` which may give unsatisfactory results depending on the plot (it worked great for `PlotRange->{{0,20},{0,20}}`). So, we take more control and indicate exactly which points we want to start our streams.  Note that `StreamPlot` uses `StreamColorFunction` instead of `PlotStyle` to change the color of the lines.

```
sP = StreamPlot[g1[x, y], {x, 0, 28}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  StreamStyle -> "Line", 
  StreamPoints -> ({14, 10} + {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 7Pi/4, Pi/4]), 
  StreamColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Darker@Yellow]];
```

Finally, we combine the plots. I start with the contour plot because it has the plot range and ticks defined.

```
Show[cP, sP, gP1, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: field lines and equipotential lines of point charge]

After defining your `f` functions and adjusting the options on the plots, you can generate plots for the other two examples.

[image: equipotential and field lines of dipole]

[image: equipotential and field lines of oppositely charged line segments]

Comment: Ahh, YESSS!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't think the last image is correct. Equipotential lines can be only parallel to conductor, and cannot cross it.

Comment: @Vitaliy, You are right. I put in half the length of the line charge. I'll edit it.

Comment: Great, Timothy, thank you ;)

Answer (score 11):

I would check out first Michael Trott blog: [**On the Importance of Being Edgy—Electrostatic and Magnetostatic Problems with Sharp Edges**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/07/20/on-the-importance-of-being-edgy-electrostatic-and-magnetostatic-problems-with-sharp-edges/). From that you can easily construct:

```
ϕLineSegment[{x_, y_, z_}] = 
 WolframAlpha[
    "electric potential of a charged line segment", {{"Result", 1}, 
     "Input"}][[1]] /. {Subscript[ϵ, 0] -> 1/(4 Pi), l -> 1, 
   Q -> 1}
```

[image]

```
Show[

 ContourPlot[ϕLineSegment[{x - 1/2, 0, 
     z}] + ϕLineSegment[{x + 1/2, 0, z}], {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> "BeachColors", 
  Contours -> 10, PlotPoints -> 60],


 StreamPlot[
  Evaluate@Grad[ϕLineSegment[{x - 1/2, 0, 
       z}] + ϕLineSegment[{x + 1/2, 0, z}], {x, z}], {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, StreamStyle -> Black],

 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-.5, -.5}, {-.5, .5}}], 
   Line[{{.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}}]}]

 ]
```

[image]

For the rest of your plots there are [**quite a few Demonstrations**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=electric%20field&start=1&limit=20). For example:

[**Electric Field Lines Due to a Collection of Point Charges**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricFieldLinesDueToACollectionOfPointCharges/)

[image: **Electric Field Lines Due to a Collection of Point Charges**]

Comment: Looks really good :)

Comment: I really like that the field lines go all the way to the point charges.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov Hi. Running this code in version 14 yields an image with only two parallel red lines.