# How can I easily visualize density plots with singularities with the least loss of detail?

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm trying to visualize electric fields.
`StreamPlot` is helpful:

```
ef[q_, source_, at_] = (k q)/Norm[source - at]^3 (at - source)
myfield[x_, y_] =
   (ef[-1, {-1, 0}, {x, y}] + ef[+1, {+1, 0}, {x, y}]) /. k -> 8.99 10^9;
StreamPlot[myfield[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Output from <code>StreamPlot</code>, correctly showing the field lines]

But when I want to see the strength of the field as well, `StreamDensityPlot` understandably chokes because $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\pm 1,0)} \lVert \texttt{myfield}[x,y] \rVert = \infty$.
This is what I get:

```
StreamDensityPlot[myfield[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Output from <code>StreamDensityPlot</code>: blue everywhere with a couple of bright dots at the poles]

Now, I can adjust the scalar field by `Min`ing the actual `Norm` with some fixed value:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{myfield[x, y], 
  Min[Norm[myfield[x, y]], 10^11]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Output from <code>StreamDensityPlot</code> with a <code>Min</code> clamp; a bit nicer]

But this requires some trial and error to find a good value, and it still doesn't look particularly great (there's noticeable clipping).
More importantly, there's really only two regions: the poles (red) and the farfield (blue); I don't really gain much insight into the field strength, at, say, $(0, \frac{1}{2})$.

Throwing a `Log` in there gives you more contrast, but you still have to fiddle with the clamp:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{myfield[x, y], 
  Min[Log[Norm[myfield[x, y]]], 28]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Output of <code>StreamDensityPlot</code> with a <code>Min</code> clamp of the <code>Log</code> transform]

Hence my question.
How can I get `StreamDensityPlot` to

- yield nice output even when the domain contains singularities,
- such that I can clearly see both the singularities and the farfield, and the regions in between,
- while still retaining a reasonable degree of physical accuracy,
- and as automatically as possible? (e.g., I don't very much like having to manually specify the scalar field)

I read the main `StreamDensityPlot` documentation and skimmed the "Options" section (that's how I found that you can manually specify the scalar field) but didn't see anything pertinent.

Comment: Also, any comments about my Mathematica code/style would be appreciated—I have much to learn!

Comment: Some very nice examples on this site, [I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/687/id-like-to-display-field-lines-for-a-point-charge-in-3-dimensions), [Plot electric potential and field](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/plot-electric-potential-and-field), [Plotting: Is anyone familiar with gradientfieldplot command?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/plotting-is-anyone-familiar-with-gradientfieldplot-command) and [Wolfram Search](http://search.wolfram.com/?query=+electric+field).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vals = Table[Norm[myfield[x, y]], {x, -3, 3, 6/100}, {y, -3, 3, 6/100}];
m = Mean@Log@Flatten@vals;
st = StandardDeviation@Log@Flatten@vals;

(* For some cases you may use these instead
   m = NIntegrate[Log@Norm[myfield[x, y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]/36;
   st = NIntegrate[(m - Log@Norm[myfield[x, y]])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]/36 // Sqrt;
*)
Manipulate[
 sta = a st; 
 StreamDensityPlot[{
       myfield[x, y],  
       Rescale[Log@Norm[myfield[x, y]], {m - sta, m + sta}]}, 
       {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
{a, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ooh, clever to use the standard deviation! I'll look into this.