# How do I begin to plot an electric field for two point charges?

Tags: plotting, syntax

I'm using Mathematica for the first time and I believe I am having trouble with the syntax.

I'm trying to plot a two point electric field and the first step in getting an electric field plot would be to write the equation. In this case I have the following equations(these equations aren't written in mathematica code, just text):

```
Ex=(k*q1(x+1))/(((x+1)^2+y^2)^(3/2))+(k*q2(x-1))/(((x-1)^2+(y-2)^2)^(3/2))
Ey=(k*q1*y)/(((x+1)^2+y^2)^(3/2))+(k*q2*y)/(((x-1)^2+(y-2)^2)^(3/2))
```

I want to end up with the following:

```
Efield= {Ex,Ey}
```

To do this I have tried the following:

```
r1 = (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2;
r2 = (x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2;
Efieldx = (q1 (x - x1))/r1^(3/2) + (q2 (x - x2))/r2^(3/2)
Efieldy = (q1 (y - y1))/r1^(3/2) + (q2 (y - y2))/r2^(3/2)
Efield = {Efieldx , Efieldy}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant, contains examples, and may help you later: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79905/how-can-i-easily-visualize-density-plots-with-singularities-with-the-least-loss

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a first time user you are jumping, if not into the deep end, then at lest into the middle of the pool. Your electric field is a function of two variables and four parameters. This can be expressed in Mathematica by

```
parametricField[q1_, q2_, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}][x_, y_] :=
  Module[{r1, r2},
    r1 = (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2;
    r2 = (x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2;
    {(q1 (x - x1))/r1^(3/2) + (q2 (x - x2))/r2^(3/2),
     (q1 (y - y1))/r1^(3/2) + (q2 (y - y2))/r2^(3/2)}]
```

To get the specific field for a given set of parameters, derive a function of two variables from `parametricField` with the parameters specified.

```
Block[{x, y},
  specificField[x_, y_] = parametricField[1, -1, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}][x, y]];
```

Now the field can be plotted.

```
StreamPlot[specificField[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: plot]

Notes

1. Now you know that you need to look up `Module`, `Block`, and `StreamPlot` in the documentation.
2. You should also look at this [tutorial on defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)..
3. `Module` is used here to localize the variables `r1` and `r2`.
4. The `Block` wrapper is used here to keep the variables `x` and `y` unevaluated even if they have values at top-level (i.e., the Global context).

Comment: Thanks for the in depth comment, I'll look into that

Comment: @thefreeman. If you like this answer you might show your appreciation by accepting it. That is, by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Imo, this is really a very good and to the point answer, I particularly like the Notes section of this answer: pointing the OP to areas of the documentation ( or other sources ) for further study.