# Plot a function based on Derivative - Gradient field

Tags: vector-calculus

I'm trying to plot the gradient field of a function in such a way that is possible to change it easily, only editing the function.

Consider the code:

```
xmin := -2; xmax := -xmin; ymin := -2; ymax := -ymin;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]
```

[image]

So, the following code produces a very fancy result:

```
VectorPlot[{2 x, 2 y}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
 StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Since `{D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]}` produces `{2 x, 2 y}` I tried to define

```
Gradf := {D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]}
```

and use

```
VectorPlot[Gradf, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
 StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamColorFunction -> Hue]
```

but I got a lot of errors as

> General::ivar: -1.99971 is not a valid variable. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

I really don't understand why it is not working.

Any idea how to solve this so I could only change the definition of `f` and plot again?

Comment: `Gradf[x_, y_] = {D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]}` instead of `Gradf := ...`. Then it works perfectly. [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/naplJ.png)

Comment: It's basically trying to find the `Derivative` of your function with the `x = some value`, instead of the `Variable` `x` because of the `SetDelayed`. So it says "-1.9something is not a valid variable" with which it can find the derivative. It's like saying `D[x,0]`.

Comment: @Öskå, I'm getting *Set::write: Tag List in {2 x,2 y}[x_,y_] is Protected. >>*. The same with `:=`.

Comment: Because you have already said "hey, `Gradf` is going to be `{2 x, 2y}`". You need to `ClearAll@Gradf` so _Mathematica_ forgets it.

Comment: @Öskå, perfect. Nice! It works. If you wish, please, post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you like, enlightened by these comments :) If not, I will do it tomorrow. It's too late here for me to write a properly written answer :)

Comment: @Öskå, OK, I'll wait. The credit is yours. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I could help. And it does look fancy indeed ;o)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot electric potential and field](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/plot-electric-potential-and-field)

Comment: Why not just the following? `With[{gradient = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
 VectorPlot[gradient, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamColorFunction -> Hue]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by defining `Gradf` as `fun := D[x^2,x]` you are saying "*Ok, you will find the `Derivative` of x^2 in terms of x **later on**.*" by using `SetDelayed (:=)`.

Thus, when `fun` appears in your `VerctorPlot` or more generally `Plot`, *Mathematica* sees it as: "*Ok, **now** I'm going to find the `Derivative` of `fun` in terms of `x`, for each `x = {0, 10}`*":

```
Plot[fun, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> General::ivar: 0.0002042857142857143` is not a valid variable.

meaning that *Mathematica*, as you commanded, is trying to find the `Derivative` of `x^2` in terms of `x` with `x` equal to `0.0002042857142857143` (*case n°1 bellow)*. Which is obviously not possible since `x` is not a `Variable` anymore.

A part of the excellent answer from rm-rf [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/1356) says:

> - If you're plotting a function, whose definition depends on the output of another possibly expensive computation (such as `Integrate`, `DSolve`, `Sum`, etc. and their numerical equivalents) use `=` or use an `Evaluate` with `:=`. Failure to do so will redo the computation for *every plot point*! This is the #1 reason for "slow plotting".

Then all you have to do is to follow what has been said above: defining your function with `Set (=)` so it `Evaluate`s the function to `x` before plotting it (*case n°2 bellow*), or `Evaluate` `fun` inside `Plot` so it `Evaluate`s the `fun` to `x` before plotting (*case n°3 bellow*). What is internally happening can be seen with `Trace`:

```
Trace@With[{fun := D[x^2, x]}, Plot[fun, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Trace@With[{fun = D[x^2, x]}, Plot[fun, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Trace@With[{fun := D[x^2, x]}, Plot[Evaluate@fun, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Now to answer the question on your specific case you have two possibilities:

```
xmin := -2; xmax := -xmin; ymin := -2; ymax := -ymin;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

With[{Gradf = {D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]}}, 
  VectorPlot[Gradf, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamColorFunction -> Hue]]

(* or *)

With[{Gradf := {D[f[x, y], x], D[f[x, y], y]}}, 
  VectorPlot[Evaluate@Gradf, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamColorFunction -> Hue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know about `Trace`. Very interesting.

Comment: @Sigur You are welcome :) I hope it helped you to understand what's really happening inside the box :)

Comment: Do you know how to plot the integral curve of the Grad field and also its image on the surface to show the path of highest grow level?

Comment: @Sigur I'm afraid that I don't really understand what you intend to do.. :) Assuming that the _"surface"_ is the `Plot3D`, what would you exactly like to do?

Comment: Ow, sorry. I'd like to plot on the 3d surface the path obtained applying the function to the path on domain corresponding to the Grad directions, that is, perpendicular to level curves. So I could see the path on the surface where the function has the faster growth. For some functions, this is easy (for example, $z=x^2+y^2$).

Comment: @Sigur I'm sorry for the lack of answer, I was not active here.. :) I guess that you could simply ask a new question about it since I don't really understand the issue, I guess that my english is not good enough.. :)