# How to plot partial derivative of an integral vs. another variable?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Just to take an example, because my original numerical integral was too complex:

```
T[t_] = NIntegrate[Exp[(eta - 1)*t], {eta, 0, 4}]
```

But when I am using

```
 Plot[D[T[t],t],{t,0,1}]
```

It seems it doesn't work.  How can I plot the derivative of the integral?

Comment: Yes. Is the D function only works for symbol equation?

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to `Evaluate`: see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GTm96.png).

Comment: Can't take derivative w.r.t a number.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `diff[t_] = D[Integrate[Exp[(eta - 1)*t], {eta, 0, 4}], t]; Plot[Evaluate@diff[t], {t, 0, 1}]` gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R9wtp.png)

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48383/plot-a-function-based-on-derivative-gradient-field/48398#48398).

Comment: But the integration can not be solved using Integrate, but only NIntegrate

Comment: See also http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Comment: `But the integration can not be solved using Integrate, but only NIntegrate` Why? It works for me: `Integrate[Exp[(eta - 1)*t], {eta, 0, 4}]`

Comment: @Öskå and others:  Since `D` will differentiate `NIntegrate`, there is another answer to this question that is not an appropriate answer to the duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative operator `D` will (symbolically) differentiate `NIntegrate`.  It's tricky to keep `NIntegrate` from evaluating and giving error messages.  If we block the evaluation of `NIntegrate` , then `D` will still differentiate it properly.  To get the `NIntegrate` expression from the function `T`, we block `NumericQ` and redefine it to evaluate to true; then `T[t]` will evaluate to the expression `NIntegrate[Exp[(eta - 3) * t], {eta, 0, 4}]`.  (I changed the OP's function slightly to make a better plot.) *[Edit: Set the attribute of the blocked `NIntegrate` to `HoldAll` to keep arguments from evaluating.  It makes no difference in the OP's example, but it's better this way.]*

```
ClearAll[T, dT];
T[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[(eta - 3)*t], {eta, 0, 4}];
Block[{NIntegrate, NumericQ = (True &)},
  SetAttributes[NIntegrate, HoldAll];
  dT[t_?NumericQ] = D[T[t], t];
  ];
T /: D[T[t_], t_] := dT[t];
```

Check:

```
?dT
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
?T
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{T[t], D[T[t], t]}], {t, 0, 2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's quite a bit faster, too, than using `ND` or `T'[t]`:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];  (* from Szabolcs' answer *)
ndT[tt_] := Block[{t}, ND[T[t], t, tt]];

Plot[Evaluate[D[T[t], t]], {t, 0, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Plot[ndT[t], {t, 0, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Plot[T'[t], {t, 0, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming // First

(*
  0.287848
  1.878337
  4.054600
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:=` when defining `T` in conjunction with [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumericQ.html):

```
Clear[T]
T[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[(eta - 1)*t], {eta, 0, 4}]
```

See [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820) for why.

Use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html) in `Plot`, or use `Evaluate` on `D`:

```
Plot[T'[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

or

```
Plot[D[T[t],t]//Evaluate, {t,0,1}]
```

`//Evaluate` simply ensures that `D[T[t],t]` will evaluate `T'[t]` before a number gets substituted for `t`.  `Plot` *tries* to get this right automatically, but it doesn't always manage.  For this reason I prefer to use [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html) explicitly.

Comment: Why do you say `ND` is more accurate? @Belisarius and I found out [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29331/16) that one (`D`) is a centred approximation, the other (`ND`) only uses values to the right of `x` to find the derivative at `x` but there's no other real difference.

Comment: @acl Thanks for the link. I don't remember exact examples.  I seem to recall that on several counts `ND` gave a good result while `Derivative` didn't.

Comment: but you can see from the link what they do...

Comment: @acl Yes, I meant that I wrote this based on a vague memory.  It seems I was not correct.  I already updated the post.

Comment: @acl, Szabolcs I think the advantage of `ND` is that it can be adjusted to the how fast the function is varying.  For example, `f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[(eta - 3)/t], {eta, 0, 4}]`.  Then `f'[0.2]` is way off, `ND[f[t], t, 0.2]` is ok, and `Apply[ND, {f[t], t, t0, Scale -> t0^2} /. t0 -> 0.2]` agrees with the exact value up to about 9 digits.  (I picked `Scale -> t0^2` because it known to be proportional to `1/f'[t0]` in this special case.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, you can control the parameters in `ND` easily (see @belisarius' addition to the answer I linked to above, it clarifies evertyhing). By the way, you can read the code for `ND`: it's in `/AddOns/Packages/NumericalCalculus/NLimit.m`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Exactly.  It's a pity `Derivative` won't let us do that.  `ND` also has `Method -> NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue):

```
T = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {int'[eta] == Exp[(eta-3) t], int[0]==0},
    int[4],
    {eta, 0, 4},
    t
]
```

where I used @Michael's variation of the integral for comparison purposes. Then:

```
Plot[{T[t], T'[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]