# Gradients of the NDSolve PDE solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to understand, how to obtain gradients of the PDE solution obtained with NDSolve. To be precise let us consider a Laplace equation from one of the examples:

```
    Clear[x, y, f];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
emesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];

f = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 2][u][x, y] + 
Derivative[2, 0][u][x, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Sin[x y], True]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ emesh]
```

This returns the interpolation function which one can plot and integrate:

```
    NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh]

(*  1.52794*10^-8  *)

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
```

[image]

This, however, does not work:

```
  g[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], x];
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
```

> Since `Integrate` does not work on this result, only `NIntegrate`does, the problem is probably that one needs to apply a numeric derivative. 
>   What and how?

Comment: Duplicate: [1301](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1301).  Also related: [48383](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48383), [50791](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50791), [69188](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69188).

Comment: @MichaelE2 but this is completely different: its on a mesh :-)

Comment: @chris I'm a little slow to understand the ":-)"  -- I thought you would object that it's a two-variable function (instead of single-variable).  :-)

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you for the most useful references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
g[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x];
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] emesh]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the `:` in the definition of `g` :-)

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds :-)

Comment: @user21 I think I learnt it from one of your posts!

Comment: If one wanted it to be `SetDelayed` for some reason one could also do `g[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[f[x, y], x]];`

Comment: @user21 feel free to answer this question instead http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84726/1089 :-) it is more in your league !

Comment: I am very much tempted but I'd like to wait a bit... ;-)

Comment: One can also use `g = Derivative[1, 0][f]`.